# NSTimer in Monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nstimer

How can I use the `NSTimer` in Monotouch to count down from some number to 0?

I have been searching alot on the web for this, but I can't find any examples or tutorials

Comment: @EBrattli show us what you did and link to the original objc source code. People will be able to point you to the issue(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use native NSTimer if .NET offers you everything with probably more convenience?

- System.Windows.Forms.Timer
- System.Timers.Timer
- System.Threading.Timer

For details when to use which one, see here (for instance): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: Be aware of using on of these timers. They are called on another thread than the UI thread. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28168694/426227) for more.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10),delegate 
{
    alert.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (1,true);
});
```

In the above code NsTimer will dismiss in 10 seconds because I mentioned in alert automatically it will click Ok button after 10 seconds. Try this I hope it will help you.

Comment: Simple implementation. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: where did the alert come from?