# Code should be executed one time after short delay

Tags: c#, ios, timer, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have this `Timer`:

```
Timer delayTimer = new Timer();
delayTimer.Interval = 500;
delayTimer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    textInputDialog.Show();
    delayTimer.Stop();
};
delayTimer.Start();
```

Here I have the following problems:

- Timer never stops. Code is executed every 500ms.
- `textInputDialog.Show();` doesn't work (perhaps cause of problem above)

What is wrong with my code?

**Alternative solutions:**

This is an alternative to timer as Jens Horstmann mentioned. And this is called on the UI thread:

```
private async Task SendWithDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    textInputDialog.Show();
}
```

Another alternative would be `NSTimer`:

```
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,500), delegate {
    textInputDialog.Show();
});
```

And to invoke a call on the UI thread you can use [`InvokeOnMainThread`](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/):

```
Timer delayTimer = new Timer();
delayTimer.Interval = 500;
delayTimer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
    delayTimer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        textInputDialog.Show();
    });
};
delayTimer.Start();
```

Comment: What is textInputDialog? A Message Box?

Comment: A `UIAlertView`. Perhaps I need a class variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: Why don't use a await Method with a short delay? You want your code run 1 time with a delay? then i think this is very good

Comment: That would also be an option. I saw that `Timer` is often used and therefore I tried this approach. Nevertheless, it would be interesting what I've done wrong in my code.

Comment: That's true. So the textInputDialog.Show(); is never called?

Comment: And my timer has no Elapsed Event, only Tick.. what have you used?

Comment: The alert should appear, but it doesn't. I also tried to define a class variable and it didn't helped. I used `System.Timers`.

Comment: i had System.Windows.Forms.Timer; :D The Answer of DrKoch is right. I can proof it. I had the same answer, but he was faster :)

Comment: @JensHorstmann Sorry ;)

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? (Please add the tag)

Comment: No Problem :) I done it intuitively so i wasn't that clear that it was that what changed the problem :D so my answer wasn't that exact enough ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop the timer before you show the dialog:

```
delayTimer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
    delayTimer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    textInputDialog.Show();
};
```

Also you probably used the wrong timer. Don't use `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers` because this involves multithreading which does not work well with winforms or WPF. (This is probably the reason your MessageBox does not show - its called on the wrong thread)

In WPF you should use `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`

**Edit**

In Winforms you should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (see comments)

Comment: @testing, as DrKoch said, System.Timers involves multithreading works with it. Rather use System.Windows.Forms.Timer, specially made for the windows forms works.

Comment: Now the timer is only called once. But it seems the second problem is because it is called on another thread as you said. I don't use `System.Windows.Forms`. Instead I use `Xamarin.iOS` and I'll add the tag. Didn't know if that would make such a difference. The only question is which timer I can use there so that it is called on the UI thread. The await method from Jens Horstmann does the job.

Comment: You need to start/register an action for the UI thread (with the dispatcher) inside your tick-event handler, google it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Here is a solution without `async`/`await`

It also happen to fit in a single statement, which is rather elegant.
This is a C#, cross-platform solution to perform an action after a delay.
Also works for a recurring task.

```
using System.Threading;

var delayTimer = new Timer((state) => // Create timer, forget about it
    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>          // Fire on main thread
        textInputDialog.Show()        // Your code goes here
    ),
    null,                             // Ignore the state
    5 * 1000,                         // 5 seconds until the 1st fire
    Timeout.Infinite);                // Do not repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
    private async Task DelayedShow()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        await _loadPop.textInputDialog.Show();
    }
```

Remember to call the method like this:

```
  BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DelayedShow());
```